# Quando usar "require", "include", "require_once" e "include_once"?

Tags: php, require, include

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação em PHP e gostaria de saber **quando e porque utilizar** `require` ou `include` ou `require_once` ou `include_once`?

Reparei também que dá para fazer destas formas e funciona:

```
require_once myfile.php;   
require_once 'myfile.php'; 
require_once ('myfile.php');
require_once ("myfile.php");
require_once "myfile.php";
```

Qualquer uma das formas está correta? Estão todas?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

A diferença entre `include` e `require` é a forma como um erro é tratado. `require` produz um erro `E_COMPILE_ERROR`, o que encerra a execução do *script*. O `include` apenas produz um *warning* que pode ser "abafado" [com `@`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84178/101).

`include_once` tem a garantia que o arquivo não será incluído novamente se ele já foi incluído antes.

`require_once` é análogo ao `include_once`

`require_once` é um *statement* portanto a sintaxe com parenteses pode confundir um pouco. No primeiro olhar pode parecer que é uma função. Por isso não aconselho seu uso, apesar de não trazer consequências prejudiciais ao programa.

## Diferença de aspas

Quanto a usar aspas simples (ou apóstrofo) ou aspas duplas (vírgulas dobradas) neste caso vai de gosto. Particularmente prefiro, sempre que possível, usar aspas duplas e só usar a simples quando é necessário. Um exemplo é quando há aspas dupla dentro do texto da *string*.

No caso específico você não pode ter nenhuma das duas aspas em nome de arquivo ou *path* por isso a dupla sempre será adequada. Inclusive as aspas duplas permitem o uso de interpolação de variável. Ex.: `include "$nome.php";` (ainda que nesse caso a sintaxe é desnecessária).

Só lembrando que o uso das aspas duplas obriga um duplo parser para tratar a interpolação. Portanto é mais eficiente usar aspas simples. Mas nada que seja muito significativo.

Eu não aconselharia usar o primeiro exemplo mostrado. Não há vantagem e causa a impressão que `myfile.php` é um símbolo do programa.

Como todas as formas são aceitas pelo PHP todas podem ser usadas, não importa a forma escolhida, o mais importante é ter padronização. Escolha uma forma e fique com ela.

Desconheço qualquer desvantagem extra além da legibilidade em qualquer forma.

Não sei se é óbvio mas você também pode usar também `require_once $minhavar;` se a variável obviamente contiver um *path* completo válido para um arquivo PHP.

O que pode diferenciar mais é o local onde um destes *statements* está sendo usado. Ele respeita o escopo. Mas isso já é outra questão.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: No campo das micro-otimizações, o debate sobre aspas duplas, simples, concatenação de variáveis dentro de strings, uso de chaves em strings para delimitar variáveis e etc. é tão polêmico, quanto controverso, com resultados de benchmarking variando de pessoa para pessoa. Eu só diria que require/include, sejam _once ou não são **construtores de linguagem**. Acredito que *statement* cabe melhor para strings de propósito definido, como uma *SQL query*.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto concordo com a primeira parte. Não gosto do termo "construtores de linguagem" porque os *statements* não necessariamente constroem alguma coisa e não conheço uma boa tradução para *statement*.

Comment: Ao pé da letra *statement* seria *afirmação*, sem qualquer contexto com esse lado da programação, mas realmente dos construtores de linguagem existentes poucos realmente contróem alguma. Mas todos sabemos que o Sr. Lerdorf não é lá um cara de muita sensatez. :p

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Esses dias estava até discutindo isso com alguns membros e não gostamos de nada apesar de "afirmação" era a tradução óbvia. +1 pela última frase :)

Answer (score 13):

> `require` é idêntico ao `include`, exceto em caso de falha que também produzirá um erro fatal de nível `E_COMPILE_ERROR`. Em outras palavras, ele irá parar o script enquanto que o  `include` apenas emite um aviso `(E_WARNING)` que permite que o script continue.

O acréscimo de `_once` (para ambos os casos) diz ao PHP para verificar se o arquivo já foi incluído, caso ele tenha sido não será incluso novamente.

Answer (score 4):

- Tratamento de erro: 
  **include**: se o arquivo não existe, a um warning (E_WARNING) é lançado mas sua aplicação continua funcionando.
  **require**: se o php não localizar o arquivo, um fatal error é lançado (E_COMPILE_ERROR). neste caso o script para.

  - **require** & **include** são funções do "tipo" statement. A semântica correta do uso destas funções é: include 'file.php' || require 'file.php';

Se você usar essas funções repetidamente na mesma página (desnecessariamente ou por acidente), o mesmo será incluso ou requerido duplicadamente.

Minha recomendação mais genérica é utilizar include_once "file"; ou require_once "file";
Pois o php verifica se o arquivo já foi incluso/requerido no script.

- OBS: função include_once, quando não encontra o arquivo informado, o seu retorno é um valor boleano false:

mas se por acaso você fazer include_once do mesmo arquivo inexistente, ele retorna true!

```
<?php var_dump(include_once "fake_file.php"); #retorno true ?>
```

Outro ponto: o uso de parênteses ao invés de "":
eu uso parênteses quando meu include está inserido em uma condicional ou outra função:

```
<?php if(!@include_once("fake.php")){echo "fake.php não incluso";}
```

Fontes: 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php

Comment: acho que não há nenhuma semântica correta visto que todas são corretas.

Comment: Quando eu digo semântica correta, eu digo seguir a risca a documentação do php, mas por via dos fatos, todas são realmente corretas :)

Answer (score -5):

Em PHP, essas quatro palavras-chave são usadas para incluir arquivos externos em um script PHP. As diferenças entre elas são:

```
require: esta palavra-chave é usada para incluir um arquivo externo que é essencial para o funcionamento do script atual. Se o arquivo não puder ser encontrado ou incluído por algum motivo, o script irá gerar um erro fatal e será interrompido.
include: esta palavra-chave é usada para incluir um arquivo externo que é apenas uma parte opcional do script atual. Se o arquivo não puder ser encontrado ou incluído por algum motivo, o script irá continuar sua execução e gerará um aviso (warning).
require_once: esta palavra-chave é semelhante a require, mas garante que o arquivo externo seja incluído apenas uma vez durante a execução do script. Se o arquivo já tiver sido incluído anteriormente, o PHP irá ignorar a inclusão e continuar a execução do script.
include_once: esta palavra-chave é semelhante a include, mas garante que o arquivo externo seja incluído apenas uma vez durante a execução do script. Se o arquivo já tiver sido incluído anteriormente, o PHP irá ignorar a inclusão e continuar a execução do script.
```

Em geral, recomenda-se usar require_once e include_once sempre que possível, pois eles ajudam a evitar erros e conflitos que podem ocorrer quando um arquivo é incluído várias vezes.