# Imprimir elemento de array associativo dentro de string sem concatenação

Tags: php, array, string, interpolação-de-string

Tenho de imprimir uma *tag* HTML através de um `echo` com o valor de um *array* associativo, porem não consigo fazer com que imprima ser o uso de concatenação.

Código `.php` (desta forma nao esta funcionando, creio que pelas aspas que envolve 'nome')

```
echo '<span class="video">{$video['nome']}</span>'
```

Comment: @QMechanic73, isto funciona porem ao fazer: echo '<span class="video">{$video['nome']}</span>' não é captado o valor do array na posição nome, é retornado um erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpolação de *string* só funciona quando você usa aspas duplas. Mas tem o inconveniente de ter que usar aspas simples em outros lugares. Você também pode usar NowDoc. Veja os exemplos abaixo:

```
$video = array('nome' => 'teste');
echo "<span class='video'>{$video['nome']}</span>";
echo <<<FIM
<span class='video'>{$video['nome']}</span>
FIM;
echo '<span class="video">' . $video['nome'] . '</span>';
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/AXzeBI). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/InterpolationString). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/String/Interpolation.php).

[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.simple).

Eu já havia falando alguma coisa sobre isso [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15290/101).

Mas pensando bem, existe algum motivo para não fazer a concatenação? Acho que deveria rever esse requisito.

Comment: ,@bigown, desta forma teria alterar todas as aspas duplas presentes dentro do html como esta class='video' que você alterou de aspas duplas para simples

Comment: Exato. Estou vendo se há alguma outra solução.

Comment: ,@bigown, irei utilizar concatenação visto que é uma solução melhor que trocar todas as aspas simples por duplas. assim sendo a forma mais simples é: echo '<span class="video">.$video['nome'].</span>'

Comment: @RicardoHenrique achei uma outra solução. Não sei se é vantagem para você mas agora você tem três opções.

Comment: ,@bigown, já havia verificado esta forma de se criar strings (com funcionamento semelhante as tags <pre>) mas não havia pensando é utiliza-las para este já que raramente as vi sendo utilizadas

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [**documentação**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) isso **não** é possível.

> Para especificar uma única citação literal, escapar-lo com uma barra
>   invertida (). Para especificar uma barra invertida, duas vezes (\).
>   Todas as outras instâncias de barra invertida será tratado como uma
>   barra invertida literal: isto significa que as outras seqüências de
>   escape que você pode ser usado para, como o \ r ou \ n, será emitido
>   literalmente, conforme especificado em vez de ter qualquer significado
>   especial.
>
> Nota: Ao contrário da sintaxe para [aspas duplas](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) e [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), [variáveis](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) e
>   sequências de escape para caracteres especiais **não serão substituídas**
>   quando elas ocorrerem dentro de strings entre aspas.

O que você pode fazer é usar concatenação mesmo.

```
$video['chave'] = "valor";
echo '<span class="video">{' .$video['chave'] .'}</span>';
```