# Identificar e pegar variáveis PUT e DELETE

Tags: php, http

Estou desenvolvendo uma solução para *API*, atualmente consigo identificar o método pelo:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']
```

Como posso pegar as variáveis `PUT` e `DELETE`? Assim como no `GET` e `POST` eu uso:

```
$_POST;
$_GET;
```

Ao realizar uma requisição para uma *API* como `PUT` ou `DELETE`, como na `API` eu capto esses valores? Espero que tenha ficado claro, e que possam me ajudar, não postei mais código pois a dúvida é bastante especifica.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Para facilitar pode criar variáveis semelhantes para consumo da sua aplicação. A única diferença é que terá que chamar alguma função para carregá-las, não será automático.

Terá que colocar isso em um arquivo e carregar de alguma forma, provavelmente com [`include`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15286/101).

```
global $_DELETE = array();
global $_PUT = array();

if (!strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'DELETE')) {
    parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $_DELETE);
}
if (!strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'PUT')) {
    parse_str(file_get_contents('php://input'), $_PUT);
}
```

Aí pode usar:

```
include_once('newVerbs.php')
echo $_PUT['email']
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/PutDelete.php).

Answer (score 9):

Ao contrario de `$_POST` e `$_GET` os métodos `DELETE`, `PUT` entre outros não possuem variáveis `pseudo-globais` que facilitam o modo de recuperar as mesmas.

Geralmente em uma `API RESTful`, nos métodos `PUT` e `DELETE` trabalhamos somente passando o `ID` do recurso que deve ser alterado ou deletado respectivamente do servidor, de modo que as requisições ficam mais ou menos assim:

Exemplo com o método `PUT`

```
PUT /123 HTTP/1.1
Host: exemplo.com.br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache

nome=teste&email=teste@teste.com
```

Exemplo com o método `DELETE`

```
DELETE /123 HTTP/1.1
Host: exemplo.com.br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Com isso podemos obter o recurso que deve ser alterado ou deletado usando `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`, e as informações podemos obter usando a variável `file_get_contents(php://input)` que pega o envio `raw`(cru) da requisição, sendo necessário trabalhar convertendo o conteúdo cru de modo que possa ser trabalhado de uma forma mais fácil.

Um exemplo de como poderia ser feito, pegado [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/897311/3956218) do Meta e adaptado

```
$metodo = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$recurso = explode("/", substr(@$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], 1));
$conteudo = file_get_contents(php://input);

switch ($metodo ) {
  case 'PUT':
    funcao_para_put($recurso, $conteudo);  
    break;
  case 'POST':
    funcao_para_post($recurso, $conteudo);  
    break;
  case 'GET':
    funcao_para_get($recurso, $conteudo);  
    break;
  case 'HEAD':
    funcao_para_head($recurso, $conteudo);  
    break;
  case 'DELETE':
    funcao_para_delete($recurso, $conteudo);  
    break;
  case 'OPTIONS':
    funcao_para_options($recurso, $conteudo);    
    break;
  default:
    header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 404 Not Found");
    die('{"msg": "Método não encontrado."}');  
    break;
}
```

No caso do DELETE precisamos apenas do ID do recurso, portanto não seria necessário pegar o `raw` da requisição, no `POST`, `GET` você poderia optar por trabalhar usando as variáveis pseudo globais mesmo, e no `PUT` usando o `file_get_contents(php://input)` assim como o @Maniero respondeu.

Comment: dei uma corrigida, comi bola ao responder rápido e sem ler haha, obrigado pelo toque :)

Answer (score -4):

Todas as requisições existem em `file_get_contents` podendo ser usada para capturar parâmetros em método put os quais não existem variáveis globais nativas em php. Porem  `file_get_contents` retorna todo o conteúdo da requisição e por isso criei uma função capaz de retornar apenas o conteúdo do parâmetro requisitado

```
$GLOBALS["_PUT"]=null;
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
        $form_data= json_encode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $key_size=52;
        $key=substr($form_data, 1, $key_size);
        $acc_params=explode($key,$form_data);
        array_shift($acc_params);
        array_pop($acc_params);
        foreach ($acc_params as $item){
            $start_key=' name=\"';
            $end_key='\"\r\n\r\n';
            $start_key_pos=strpos($item,$start_key)+strlen($start_key);
            $end_key_pos=strpos($item,$end_key);
            
            $key=substr($item, $start_key_pos, ($end_key_pos-$start_key_pos));
            
            $end_value='\r\n';
            $value=substr($item, $end_key_pos+strlen($end_key), -strlen($end_value));
            $_PUT[$key]=$value;
        }
        $GLOBALS["_PUT"]=$_PUT;
    }


echo $GLOBALS["_PUT"]["input_form"]
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

```
$GLOBALS["_PUT"]=null;
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
    $form_data= json_encode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $key_size=52;
    $key=substr($form_data, 1, $key_size);
    $acc_params=explode($key,$form_data);
    array_shift($acc_params);
    array_pop($acc_params);
    foreach ($acc_params as $item){
        $start_key=' name=\"';
        $end_key='\"\r\n\r\n';
        $start_key_pos=strpos($item,$start_key)+strlen($start_key);
        $end_key_pos=strpos($item,$end_key);
        
        $key=substr($item, $start_key_pos, ($end_key_pos-$start_key_pos));
        
        $end_value='\r\n';
        $value=substr($item, $end_key_pos+strlen($end_key), -strlen($end_value));
        $_PUT[$key]=$value;
    }
    $GLOBALS["_PUT"]=$_PUT;
}

if (!function_exists("getParameter")){
    function getParameter($parameter)
    {
        $value=null;
        if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')&& (isset($_POST[$parameter]))){
            $value=$_POST[$parameter];
        }
        else if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT')&& (isset($GLOBALS["_PUT"][$parameter])))
        {
                $value=$GLOBALS["_PUT"][$parameter];
        }
        else if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'DELETE')&& (isset($_DELETE[$parameter]))){
            $value=$_DELETE[$parameter];
        }
        else if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PATCH')&& (isset($_PATCH[$parameter]))){
            $value=$_PATCH[$parameter];
        }
        else if(isset($_GET[$parameter])){
            $value=$_GET[$parameter];
        }
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).