# Palavra reservada include ou "use" no PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, namespace, include

Vi em algum lugar que a palavra reservado `include` no PHP deveria ser usada
apenas em programação procedural, e que em programação orientada a objetos
deveria optar-se pela palavra reservada `use`.

Não achei nada que me levasse a crer que a substituição é correta. Ou seja, é a mesma coisa usar include ou use para chamar outras partes do programa, que seria como um importe, não é?

Comment: Bom eu usei assim no programa:                                                              <?php
namespace site;

include_once 'site/modulo1/Pessoa.php';

use site\modulo1\Pessoa;
use DAO\Connection;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso não faz sentido, pelo menos não sem uma explicação. Se viu em algum lugar e não explicou porque, ignore, possivelmente é gosto da pessoa. Se tiver uma explicação, aí se você entender os fundamentos poderá avaliar se aquilo faz sentido ou não.

Se não usar o `include` carregará os arquivos auxiliares para aquela aplicação de que forma? Tem outras [palavras semelhantes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15286/101), mas faz essencialmente o mesmo. Existe formas de carregamento automático. O que pode ser questionável o seu uso. E se existe é por falha estrutural da linguagem. Nada tem a ver com orientação a objeto. Na verdade pouco do que as pessoas acham sobre OOP realmente é OOP, e muito de OO as pessoas desconhecem mesmo achando que estão usando este paradigma.

O `include` carrega um código fonte, o `use` habilita o uso de um *namespace*. Um espaço de nomes é só uma forma de organizar códigos com um sobrenome para facilitar o acesso e desambiguar nomes iguais que fazem coisas distintas. O códigos são mais físicos, os *namespaces* são mais lógicos. Tem [uma pergunta sobre o assunto em outra linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101), mas a ideia básica é a mesma.

Mesmo o `use` tem a ver com modularização não com orientação a objeto.

Toda vez que alguém falar sobre [procedural X OOP em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101) tem uma chance da pessoa não entender sobre OOP e usa só porque é moda, aí ela acha que se ela fizer procedural está fazendo algo errado, o que está longe de ser verdade, especialmente em PHP.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: No link  http://www.diogomatheus.com.br/blog/php/entendendo-namespaces-no-php/  encontrei algo sobre o namespaces e pelo que entendi da pra usar como importe. Contudo fiquei pensando e se quiser usar uma vez só , sei lá devo usaro include_once então? É que estou fazendo uma aplicação com phpOO e não quero começar errado!  Pode ser uma mistura disso... tudo. Cara como proceder?

Comment: Ele não importa nada, apenas disponibiliza para uso. Uma coisa não tem nada a ver com outra, um faz uma coisa, o outro faz outra coisa, um não substitui o outro. Alguma coisa me diz que já começou errado só pelo jeito que está falando :)