# Pegar função em php e adicionar em outro arquivo

Tags: php, html

Estou com dificuldade em pega 3 funções que já estão escritas e colocar em outro arquivo, tentei de tudo e não consegui.

O código abaixo serve para listagem de diretórios e arquivos, as funções que eu quero para adicionar em outro código são as de apagar arquivos e diretórios, criar diretórios e a função de upload.

PREVIEW [image: IMAGEM DO SCRIPT]

Não deu de adicionar a parte do html por exceder o limite de caracteres, no entanto vou deixa o link do autor para o código completo.

[PÁGINA COM O LINK COMPLETO](https://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/php-directory-listing-script)

```js
<?php
session_start();
class DirectoryListing {
 /*
 ====================================================================================================
 Evoluted Directory Listing Script - Version 4
 www.evoluted.net / info@evoluted.net
 https://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/php-directory-listing-script
 ====================================================================================================

 SYSTEM REQUIREMENTS
 ====================================================================================================
 This script requires a PHP version 5.3 or above (5.6 is the recommended minimum) along with the GD
 library if you wish to use the thumbnail/image preview functionality. For (optional) unzip
 functionality, you'll need the ZipArchive php extension.

 HOW TO USE
 ====================================================================================================
 1) Unzip the provided files.
 2) Upload the index.php file to the directory you wish to use the script on
 3) Browse to the directory to see the script in action
 4) Optionally change any of the settings below

 CONFIGURATION
 ====================================================================================================
 You may edit any of the variables in this section to alter how the directory listing script will
 function. Please read the notes above each variable for details on what they change.
 */

 // The top level directory where this script is located, or alternatively one of it's sub-directories
 public $startDirectory = '.';

 // An optional title to show in the address bar and at the top of your page (set to null to leave blank)
 public $pageTitle = 'Evoluted Directory Listing Script';

 // The URL of this script. Optionally set if your server is unable to detect the paths of files
 public $includeUrl = false;

 // If you've enabled the includeUrl parameter above, enter the full url to the directory the index.php file
 // is located in here, followed by a forward slash.
 public $directoryUrl = 'http://yoursite.com/main-directory-name-here/';

 // Set to true to list all sub-directories and allow them to be browsed
 public $showSubDirectories = true;

 // Set to true to open all file links in a new browser tab
 public $openLinksInNewTab = true;

 // Set to true to show thumbnail previews of any images
 public $showThumbnails = true;

 // Set to true to allow new directories to be created.
 public $enableDirectoryCreation = true;

 // Set to true to allow file uploads (NOTE: you should set a password if you enable this!)
 public $enableUploads = true;

 // Enable multi-file uploads (NOTE: This makes use of javascript libraries hosted by Google so an internet connection is required.)
 public $enableMultiFileUploads = true;

 // Set to true to overwrite files on the server if they have the same name as a file being uploaded
 public $overwriteOnUpload = false;

 // Set to true to enable file deletion options
 public $enableFileDeletion = true;

 // Set to true to enable directory deletion options (only available when the directory is empty)
 public $enableDirectoryDeletion = true;

 // List of all mime types that can be uploaded. Full list of mime types: http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml
 public $allowedUploadMimeTypes = array(
  'image/jpeg',
  'image/gif',
  'image/png',
  'image/bmp',
  'audio/mpeg',
  'audio/mp3',
  'audio/mp4',
  'audio/x-aac',
  'audio/x-aiff',
  'audio/x-ms-wma',
  'audio/midi',
  'audio/ogg',
  'video/ogg',
  'video/webm',
  'video/quicktime',
  'video/x-msvideo',
  'video/x-flv',
  'video/h261',
  'video/h263',
  'video/h264',
  'video/jpeg',
  'text/plain',
  'text/html',
  'text/css',
  'text/csv',
  'text/calendar',
  'application/pdf',
  'application/x-pdf',
  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', // MS Word (modern)
  'application/msword',
  'application/vnd.ms-excel',
  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', // MS Excel (modern)
  'application/zip',
  'application/x-tar'
 );

 // Set to true to unzip any zip files that are uploaded (note - will overwrite files of the same name!)
 public $enableUnzipping = true;

 // If you've enabled unzipping, you can optionally delete the original zip file after its uploaded by setting this to true.
 public $deleteZipAfterUploading = false;

 // The Evoluted Directory Listing Script uses Bootstrap. By setting this value to true, a nicer theme will be loaded remotely.
 // Setting this to false will make the directory listing script use the default bootstrap style, loaded locally.
 public $enableTheme = true;

 // Set to true to require a password be entered before being able to use the script
 public $passwordProtect = false;

 // The password to require to use this script (only used if $passwordProtect is set to true)
 public $password = 'password';

 // Optional. Allow restricted access only to whitelisted IP addresses
 public $enableIpWhitelist = false;

 // List of IP's to allow access to the script (only used if $enableIpWhitelist is true)
 public $ipWhitelist = array(
  '127.0.0.1'
 );

 // File extensions to block from showing in the directory listing
 public $ignoredFileExtensions = array(
  'php',
  'ini',
 );

 // File names to block from showing in the directory listing
 public $ignoredFileNames = array(
  '.htaccess',
  '.DS_Store',
  'Thumbs.db',
 );

 // Directories to block from showing in the directory listing
 public $ignoredDirectories = array(

 );

 // Files that begin with a dot are usually hidden files. Set this to false if you wish to show these hiden files.
 public $ignoreDotFiles = true;

 // Works the same way as $ignoreDotFiles but with directories.
 public $ignoreDotDirectories = true;

 /*
 ====================================================================================================
 You shouldn't need to edit anything below this line unless you wish to add functionality to the
 script. You should only edit this area if you know what you are doing!
 ====================================================================================================
 */
 private $__previewMimeTypes = array(
  'image/gif',
  'image/jpeg',
  'image/png',
  'image/bmp'
 );

 private $__currentDirectory = null;

 private $__fileList = array();

 private $__directoryList = array();

 private $__debug = true;

 public $sortBy = 'name';

 public $sortableFields = array(
  'name',
  'size',
  'modified'
 );

 private $__sortOrder = 'asc';

 public function __construct() {
  define('DS', '/');
 }

 public function run() {
  if ($this->enableIpWhitelist) {
   $this->__ipWhitelistCheck();
  }

  $this->__currentDirectory = $this->startDirectory;

  // Sorting
  if (isset($_GET['order']) && in_array($_GET['order'], $this->sortableFields)) {
   $this->sortBy = $_GET['order'];
  }

  if (isset($_GET['sort']) && ($_GET['sort'] == 'asc' || $_GET['sort'] == 'desc')) {
   $this->__sortOrder = $_GET['sort'];
  }

  if (isset($_GET['dir'])) {
   if (isset($_GET['delete']) && $this->enableDirectoryDeletion) {
    $this->deleteDirectory();
   }

   $this->__currentDirectory = $_GET['dir'];
   return $this->__display();
  } elseif (isset($_GET['preview'])) {
   $this->__generatePreview($_GET['preview']);
  } else {
   return $this->__display();
  }
 }

 public function login() {
  $password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  if ($password === $this->password) {
   $_SESSION['evdir_loggedin'] = true;
   unset($_SESSION['evdir_loginfail']);
  } else {
   $_SESSION['evdir_loginfail'] = true;
   unset($_SESSION['evdir_loggedin']);

  }
 }

 public function upload() {
  $files = $this->__formatUploadArray($_FILES['upload']);

  if ($this->enableUploads) {
   if ($this->enableMultiFileUploads) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
     $status = $this->__processUpload($file);
    }
   } else {
    $file = $files[0];
    $status = $this->__processUpload($file);
   }

   return $status;
  }
  return false;
 }

 private function __formatUploadArray($files) {
  $fileAry = array();
  $fileCount = count($files['name']);
  $fileKeys = array_keys($files);

  for ($i = 0; $i < $fileCount; $i++) {
   foreach ($fileKeys as $key) {
    $fileAry[$i][$key] = $files[$key][$i];
   }
  }

  return $fileAry;
 }

 private function __processUpload($file) {
  if (isset($_GET['dir'])) {
   $this->__currentDirectory = $_GET['dir'];
  }

  if (! $this->__currentDirectory) {
   $filePath = realpath($this->startDirectory);
  } else {
   $this->__currentDirectory = str_replace('..', '', $this->__currentDirectory);
   $this->__currentDirectory = ltrim($this->__currentDirectory, "/");
   $filePath = realpath($this->__currentDirectory);
  }

  $filePath = $filePath . DS . $file['name'];

  if (! empty($file)) {

   if (! $this->overwriteOnUpload) {
    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
     return 2;
    }
   }

   if (! in_array(mime_content_type($file['tmp_name']), $this->allowedUploadMimeTypes)) {
    return 3;
   }

   move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $filePath);

   if (mime_content_type($filePath) == 'application/zip' && $this->enableUnzipping && class_exists('ZipArchive')) {

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $result = $zip->open($filePath);
    $zip->extractTo(realpath($this->__currentDirectory));
    $zip->close();

    if ($this->deleteZipAfterUploading) {
     // Delete the zip file
     unlink($filePath);
    }


   }

   return true;
  }
 }

 public function deleteFile() {
  if (isset($_GET['deleteFile'])) {
   $file = $_GET['deleteFile'];

   // Clean file path
   $file = str_replace('..', '', $file);
   $file = ltrim($file, "/");

   // Work out full file path
   $filePath = __DIR__ . $this->__currentDirectory . '/' . $file;

   if (file_exists($filePath) && is_file($filePath)) {
    return unlink($filePath);
   }
   return false;
  }
 }

 public function deleteDirectory() {
  if (isset($_GET['dir'])) {
   $dir = $_GET['dir'];
   // Clean dir path
   $dir = str_replace('..', '', $dir);
   $dir = ltrim($dir, "/");

   // Work out full directory path
   $dirPath = __DIR__ . '/' . $dir;

   if (file_exists($dirPath) && is_dir($dirPath)) {

    $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

    foreach ($files as $file) {
     if ($file->isDir()) {
      rmdir($file->getRealPath());
     } else {
      unlink($file->getRealPath());
     }
    }
    return rmdir($dir);
   }
  }
  return false;
 }

 public function createDirectory() {
  if ($this->enableDirectoryCreation) {
   $directoryName = $_POST['directory'];

   // Convert spaces
   $directoryName = str_replace(' ', '_', $directoryName);

   // Clean up formatting
   $directoryName = preg_replace('/[^\w-_]/', '', $directoryName);

   if (isset($_GET['dir'])) {
    $this->__currentDirectory = $_GET['dir'];
   }

   if (! $this->__currentDirectory) {
    $filePath = realpath($this->startDirectory);
   } else {
    $this->__currentDirectory = str_replace('..', '', $this->__currentDirectory);
    $filePath = realpath($this->__currentDirectory);
   }

   $filePath = $filePath . DS . strtolower($directoryName);

   if (file_exists($filePath)) {
    return false;
   }

   return mkdir($filePath, 0755);

  }
  return false;
 }

 public function sortUrl($sort) {

  // Get current URL parts
  $urlParts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

  $url = '';

  if (isset($urlParts['scheme'])) {
   $url = $urlParts['scheme'] . '://';
  }

  if (isset($urlParts['host'])) {
   $url .= $urlParts['host'];
  }

  if (isset($urlParts['path'])) {
   $url .= $urlParts['path'];
  }


  // Extract query string
  if (isset($urlParts['query'])) {
   $queryString = $urlParts['query'];

   parse_str($queryString, $queryParts);

   // work out if we're already sorting by the current heading
   if (isset($queryParts['order']) && $queryParts['order'] == $sort) {
    // Yes we are, just switch the sort option!
    if (isset($queryParts['sort'])) {
     if ($queryParts['sort'] == 'asc') {
      $queryParts['sort'] = 'desc';
     } else {
      $queryParts['sort'] = 'asc';
     }
    }
   } else {
    $queryParts['order'] = $sort;
    $queryParts['sort'] = 'asc';
   }

   // Now convert back to a string
   $queryString = http_build_query($queryParts);

   $url .= '?' . $queryString;
  } else {
   $order = 'asc';
   if ($sort == $this->sortBy) {
    $order = 'desc';
   }
   $queryString = 'order=' . $sort . '&sort=' . $order;
   $url .= '?' . $queryString;
  }

  return $url;
 }

 public function sortClass($sort) {
  $class = $sort . '_';

  if ($this->sortBy == $sort) {
   if ($this->__sortOrder == 'desc') {
    $class .= 'desc sort_desc';
   } else {
    $class .= 'asc sort_asc';
   }
  } else {
   $class = '';
  }
  return $class;
 }

 private function __ipWhitelistCheck() {
  // Get the users ip
  $userIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

  if (! in_array($userIp, $this->ipWhitelist)) {
   header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
   die('Your IP address (' . $userIp . ') is not authorized to access this file.');
  }
 }

 private function __display() {
  if ($this->__currentDirectory != '.' && !$this->__endsWith($this->__currentDirectory, DS)) {
   $this->__currentDirectory = $this->__currentDirectory . DS;
  }

  return $this->__loadDirectory($this->__currentDirectory);
 }

 private function __loadDirectory($path) {
  $files = $this->__scanDir($path);

  if (! empty($files)) {
   // Strip excludes files, directories and filetypes
   $files = $this->__cleanFileList($files);
   foreach ($files as $file) {
    $filePath = realpath($this->__currentDirectory . DS . $file);

    if ($this->__isDirectory($filePath)) {

     if (! $this->includeUrl) {
      $urlParts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

      $dirUrl = '';

      if (isset($urlParts['scheme'])) {
       $dirUrl = $urlParts['scheme'] . '://';
      }

      if (isset($urlParts['host'])) {
       $dirUrl .= $urlParts['host'];
      }

      if (isset($urlParts['path'])) {
       $dirUrl .= $urlParts['path'];
      }
     } else {
      $dirUrl = $this->directoryUrl;
     }

     if ($this->__currentDirectory != '' && $this->__currentDirectory != '.') {
      $dirUrl .= '?dir=' . rawurlencode($this->__currentDirectory) . rawurlencode($file);
     } else {
      $dirUrl .= '?dir=' . rawurlencode($file);
     }

     $this->__directoryList[$file] = array(
      'name' => rawurldecode($file),
      'path' => $filePath,
      'type' => 'dir',
      'url' => $dirUrl
     );
    } else {
     $this->__fileList[$file] = $this->__getFileType($filePath, $this->__currentDirectory . DS . $file);
    }
   }
  }

  if (! $this->showSubDirectories) {
   $this->__directoryList = null;
  }

  $data = array(
   'currentPath' => $this->__currentDirectory,
   'directoryTree' => $this->__getDirectoryTree(),
   'files' => $this->__setSorting($this->__fileList),
   'directories' => $this->__directoryList,
   'requirePassword' => $this->passwordProtect,
   'enableUploads' => $this->enableUploads
  );

  return $data;
 }

 private function __setSorting($data) {
  $sortOrder = '';
  $sortBy = '';

  // Sort the files
  if ($this->sortBy == 'name') {
   function compareByName($a, $b) {
    return strnatcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
   }

   usort($data, 'compareByName');
   $this->soryBy = 'name';
  } elseif ($this->sortBy == 'size') {
   function compareBySize($a, $b) {
    return strnatcasecmp($a['size_bytes'], $b['size_bytes']);
   }

   usort($data, 'compareBySize');
   $this->soryBy = 'size';
  } elseif ($this->sortBy == 'modified') {
   function compareByModified($a, $b) {
    return strnatcasecmp($a['modified'], $b['modified']);
   }

   usort($data, 'compareByModified');
   $this->soryBy = 'modified';
  }

  if ($this->__sortOrder == 'desc') {
   $data = array_reverse($data);
  }
  return $data;
 }

 private function __scanDir($dir) {
  // Prevent browsing up the directory path.
  if (strstr($dir, '../')) {
   return false;
  }

  if ($dir == '/') {
   $dir = $this->startDirectory;
   $this->__currentDirectory = $dir;
  }

  $strippedDir = str_replace('/', '', $dir);

  $dir = ltrim($dir, "/");

  // Prevent listing blacklisted directories
  if (in_array($strippedDir, $this->ignoredDirectories)) {
   return false;
  }

  if (! file_exists($dir) || !is_dir($dir)) {
   return false;
  }

  return scandir($dir);
 }

 private function __cleanFileList($files) {
  $this->ignoredDirectories[] = '.';
  $this->ignoredDirectories[] = '..';
  foreach ($files as $key => $file) {

   // Remove unwanted directories
   if ($this->__isDirectory(realpath($file)) && in_array($file, $this->ignoredDirectories)) {
    unset($files[$key]);
   }

   // Remove dot directories (if enables)
   if ($this->ignoreDotDirectories && substr($file, 0, 1) === '.') {
    unset($files[$key]);
   }

   // Remove unwanted files
   if (! $this->__isDirectory(realpath($file)) && in_array($file, $this->ignoredFileNames)) {
    unset($files[$key]);
   }
   // Remove unwanted file extensions
   if (! $this->__isDirectory(realpath($file))) {

    $info = pathinfo(mb_convert_encoding($file, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8'));

    if (isset($info['extension'])) {
     $extension = $info['extension'];

     if (in_array($extension, $this->ignoredFileExtensions)) {
      unset($files[$key]);
     }
    }

    // If dot files want ignoring, do that next
    if ($this->ignoreDotFiles) {

     if (substr($file, 0, 1) == '.') {
      unset($files[$key]);
     }
    }
   }
  }
  return $files;
 }

 private function __isDirectory($file) {
  if ($file == $this->__currentDirectory . DS . '.' || $file == $this->__currentDirectory . DS . '..') {
   return true;
  }
  $file = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');

  if (filetype($file) == 'dir') {
   return true;
  }

  return false;
 }

 /**
  * __getFileType
  *
  * Returns the formatted array of file data used for thre directory listing.
  *
  * @param  string $filePath Full path to the file
  * @return array   Array of data for the file
  */
 private function __getFileType($filePath, $relativePath = null) {
  $fi = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

  if (! file_exists($filePath)) {
   return false;
  }

  $type = $fi->file($filePath);

  $filePathInfo = pathinfo($filePath);

  $fileSize = filesize($filePath);

  $fileModified = filemtime($filePath);

  $filePreview = false;

  // Check if the file type supports previews
  if ($this->__supportsPreviews($type) && $this->showThumbnails) {
   $filePreview = true;
  }

  return array(
   'name' => $filePathInfo['basename'],
   'extension' => (isset($filePathInfo['extension']) ? $filePathInfo['extension'] : null),
   'dir' => $filePathInfo['dirname'],
   'path' => $filePath,
   'relativePath' => $relativePath,
   'size' => $this->__formatSize($fileSize),
   'size_bytes' => $fileSize,
   'modified' => $fileModified,
   'type' => 'file',
   'mime' => $type,
   'url' => $this->__getUrl($filePathInfo['basename']),
   'preview' => $filePreview,
   'target' => ($this->openLinksInNewTab ? '_blank' : '_parent')
  );
 }

 private function __supportsPreviews($type) {
  if (in_array($type, $this->__previewMimeTypes)) {
   return true;
  }
  return false;
 }

 /**
  * __getUrl
  *
  * Returns the url to the file.
  *
  * @param  string $file filename
  * @return string   url of the file
  */
 private function __getUrl($file) {
  if (! $this->includeUrl) {
   $dirUrl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

   $urlParts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

   $dirUrl = '';

   if (isset($urlParts['scheme'])) {
    $dirUrl = $urlParts['scheme'] . '://';
   }

   if (isset($urlParts['host'])) {
    $dirUrl .= $urlParts['host'];
   }

   if (isset($urlParts['path'])) {
    $dirUrl .= $urlParts['path'];
   }
  } else {
   $dirUrl = $this->directoryUrl;
  }

  if ($this->__currentDirectory != '.') {
   $dirUrl = $dirUrl . $this->__currentDirectory;
  }
  return $dirUrl . rawurlencode($file);
 }

 private function __getDirectoryTree() {
  $dirString = $this->__currentDirectory;
  $directoryTree = array();

  $directoryTree['./'] = 'Index';

  if (substr_count($dirString, '/') >= 0) {
   $items = explode("/", $dirString);
   $items = array_filter($items);
   $path = '';
   foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') {
     continue;
    }
    $path .= rawurlencode($item) . '/';
    $directoryTree[$path] = $item;
   }
  }

  $directoryTree = array_filter($directoryTree);

  return $directoryTree;
 }

 private function __endsWith($haystack, $needle) {
  return $needle === "" || (($temp = strlen($haystack) - strlen($needle)) >= 0 && strpos($haystack, $needle, $temp) !== false);
 }

 private function __generatePreview($filePath) {
  $file = $this->__getFileType($filePath);

  if ($file['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
   $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['path']);
  } elseif ($file['mime'] == 'image/png') {
   $image = imagecreatefrompng($file['path']);
  } elseif ($file['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
   $image = imagecreatefromgif($file['path']);
  } else {
   die();
  }

  $oldX = imageSX($image);
  $oldY = imageSY($image);

  $newW = 250;
  $newH = 250;

  if ($oldX > $oldY) {
   $thumbW = $newW;
   $thumbH = $oldY * ($newH / $oldX);
  }
  if ($oldX < $oldY) {
   $thumbW = $oldX * ($newW / $oldY);
   $thumbH = $newH;
  }
  if ($oldX == $oldY) {
   $thumbW = $newW;
   $thumbH = $newW;
  }

  header('Content-Type: ' . $file['mime']);

  $newImg = ImageCreateTrueColor($thumbW, $thumbH);

  imagecopyresampled($newImg, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbW, $thumbH, $oldX, $oldY);

  if ($file['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
   imagejpeg($newImg);
  } elseif ($file['mime'] == 'image/png') {
   imagepng($newImg);
  } elseif ($file['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
   imagegif($newImg);
  }
  imagedestroy($newImg);
  die();
 }

 private function __formatSize($bytes) {
  $units = array('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB');

  $bytes = max($bytes, 0);
  $pow = floor(($bytes ? log($bytes) : 0) / log(1024));
  $pow = min($pow, count($units) - 1);

  $bytes /= pow(1024, $pow);

  return round($bytes, 2) . ' ' . $units[$pow];
 }

}

$listing = new DirectoryListing();

$successMsg = null;
$errorMsg = null;

if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
 $listing->login();

 if (isset($_SESSION['evdir_loginfail'])) {
  $errorMsg = 'Login Failed! Please check you entered the correct password an try again.';
  unset($_SESSION['evdir_loginfail']);
 }

} elseif (isset($_FILES['upload'])) {
 $uploadStatus = $listing->upload();
 if ($uploadStatus == 1) {
  $successMsg = 'Your file was successfully uploaded!';
 } elseif ($uploadStatus == 2) {
  $errorMsg = 'Your file could not be uploaded. A file with that name already exists.';
 } elseif ($uploadStatus == 3) {
  $errorMsg = 'Your file could not be uploaded as the file type is blocked.';
 }
} elseif (isset($_POST['directory'])) {
 if ($listing->createDirectory()) {
  $successMsg = 'Directory Created!';
 } else {
  $errorMsg = 'There was a problem creating your directory.';
 }
} elseif (isset($_GET['deleteFile']) && $listing->enableFileDeletion) {
 if ($listing->deleteFile()) {
  $successMsg = 'The file was successfully deleted!';
 } else {
  $errorMsg = 'The selected file could not be deleted. Please check your file permissions and try again.';
 }
} elseif (isset($_GET['dir']) && isset($_GET['delete']) && $listing->enableDirectoryDeletion) {
 if ($listing->deleteDirectory()) {
  $successMsg = 'The directory was successfully deleted!';
  unset($_GET['dir']);
 } else {
  $errorMsg = 'The selected directory could not be deleted. Please check your file permissions and try again.';
 }
}

$data = $listing->run();

function pr($data, $die = false) {
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($data);
 echo '</pre>';

 if ($die) {
  die();
 }
}
?>
```

Os créditos do criador do estão no próprio código.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar:

```
require "nome/arquivo_funcoes.php";
```

Ou

```
require_once 'nome/arquivo_funcoes.php';
```

Ou

```
include("nome/arquivo_funcoes.php");
```

Ou

```
include_once nome/arquivo_funcoes.php;
```

E chamar a função da outra página como se ela estivesse na página, que na verdade é o que acontece

[Nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15286/o-que-usar-require-include-require-once-include-once) é explicado a diferença entre eles

Comment: eu pensei nisso, porem o código que eu estou usando e bem simples, utilizo somente um arquivo, que seria o index.php, se eu fizesse isso ficaria 2 arquivos na pasta, desnecessariamente :(

Comment: Na minha humilde opinião, seria bom deixar essas funções em um arquivo separado, além de manter mais organizado, deixa o arquivo index menor tornando mais fácil a manutenção já que você só verá o que pode ser mudado e diminui erros que podem surgir por sem querer apaguei/renomeei uma variável. O ideal mesmo, seria ter uma pasta exclusiva para esses arquivos que você pega da internet e não vai mudar, esse é o padrão usado hoje, arquivos de bibliotecas, frameworks etc ficam em uma pasta distinta que não precisará ser constantemente empurrada em sistemas de versionamento ou até mesmo um drive

Comment: realmente fica melhor, não sou contra sua ideia, só que eu gostaria de deixa apenas um único arquivo, sem ter que fica criando bibliotecas. Digamos que eu tenho uma pasta no meu servidor, dentro do www, então dentro dessa pasta eu tenho vários arquivos como por exemplo file.srt, a ideia e apenas adicionar esse arquivo index.php para lista os arquivos e se precisar adicionar outro por upload ou apagar algum q já exista. Uma simples pagina, para uma coisa simples.

Comment: de uma olhada de como esta ficando, atualmente estou utilizando seu método, porem gostaria de deixa somente um único arquivo index.php, sem ter que ter outro na mesma pasta - https://prnt.sc/je6v9i

Comment: Basicamente um FTP, mas então não entendi você disse que quer deixar tudo no mesmo arquivo e a pergunta é _"Pegar função em php e adicionar em outro arquivo"_, está contraditório

Comment: eu quero apenas separa essas 3 funções que esta nesse código que eu coloquei acima, nele tem varias funções, porem tem uma que faz o upload para a pasta, tem uma que cria pastas e tem uma que apaga o arquivo ou pasta do servidor.
Esse arquivo acima faz a mesma coisa que o outro q eu tenho, porem o outro que eu tenho já esta perfeito, eu apenas quero adicionar essas funções nele para complementar, você lembra quando me ajudou a arrumar quele problema com plurais em time_ago? eu quero adicionar essas funções naquele arquivo que a gente corrigiu semana passada.

Comment: ficou contraditório realmente kkk, não sou muito bom em explicar as coisas. A minha dificuldade em fazer isso sozinho foi porque esse arquivo esta dentro de uma class, nunca vi isso kkkk

Comment: Se as funções estão dentro de uma classe basta instanciar a classe ou retirar ela