# Trazer resultado de um sum em tela

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando criar um `sum` e apresentar em tela. Porém quase todos os exemplos que vejo usam a chamada do `$conn` e no meu caso estou usando um arquivo que já traz a conexão com o banco e o *select + query + row* estão apresentando erro.

Segue o código:

```html
<?php
require 'config.php';
?>

<?php
$gasto = "select sum(buy) from home"
$resultgasto = mysqli_query($gasto);
$resultGasto_query = mysqli_fetch_row($resultgasto);

?>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>Tabela poker</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
   </head>
   <body>

      <table  style="padding-top: 20px;height: 202px;width: 171px;" ID="tabelabk1"  >
         <tr>
            <th>(%)</th>
            <th>VALOR</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td bgcolor="darkgreen">Gasto</td>
           <?php <td bgcolor="#FF6347">.$$resultGasto_query['buy'].</td>?>
         </tr>
         
         
         
         
         
         <?php
require_once 'config.php';
?>

<?php
$gasto = "select sum(buy) as buy from home;";
$resultgasto = mysqli_query($pdo, $gasto);
$resultGasto_query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultgasto);
?>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>Tabela poker</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
   </head>
   <body>
 
         <tr>
            <td bgcolor="darkgreen">Gasto</td>
            <td bgcolor="#FF6347"><?php echo $resultGasto_query['buy']; ?></td>
         </tr>



<?php

$dsn = "mysql:dbname=poker;host=localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";


try {
 $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);
 
} 

catch(PDOExeption $e) {
 echo "falhou: ".$e->getMessage();
}

?>


( ! ) Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in C:\wamp\www\poker\home\index.php on line 7
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0003 135360 {main}( ) ...\index.php:0
2 0.0040 142680 mysqli_query ( ) ...\index.php:7

( ! ) Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\poker\home\index.php on line 8
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0003 135360 {main}( ) ...\index.php:0
2 0.0555 143080 mysqli_fetch_assoc ( ) ...\index.php:8





    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM home ORDER BY id_home";
    $sql = $conexao->query($sql);
  
    if($sql->rowCount() > 0) {
       foreach ($sql->fetchAll() as $home) {
        
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$home['id_home'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$home['buy'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$home['premio'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$home['torneio'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$home['jogadores'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$home['saldo'].'</td>';
        echo '<tr>';
       }
       
    }
```

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
?>

<?php
$gasto = "select sum(buy) as buy from home;";
$resultgasto = mysqli_query($pdo, $gasto);
$resultGasto_query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultgasto);
?>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>Tabela poker</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
   </head>
   <body>

         <tr>
            <td bgcolor="darkgreen">Gasto</td>
            <td bgcolor="#FF6347"><?php echo $resultGasto_query['buy']; ?></td>
         </tr>



<?php

$dsn = "mysql:dbname=poker;host=localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";


try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);

} 

catch(PDOExeption $e) {
    echo "falhou: ".$e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

> ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in C:\wamp\www\poker\home\index.php on line 7
>   Call Stack
>   #    Time    Memory  Function    Location
>   1 0.0003  135360  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
>   2 0.0040  142680  mysqli_query ( )    ...\index.php:7
>
> ( ! ) Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\wamp\www\poker\home\index.php on line 8
>   Call Stack
>   #    Time    Memory  Function    Location
>   1 0.0003  135360  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0
>   2 0.0555  143080  mysqli_fetch_assoc ( )  ...\index.php:8

Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::rowCount() in C:\wamp\www\poker\home\index.php on line 126
Call Stack

## Time    Memory  Function    Location

1   0.0002  135728  {main}( )   ...\index.php:0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> no meu caso estou usando um arquivo que ja trazer a conexao ocm o banco

Para começar, `include` e `require` têm diferenças significativas. No seu caso, presumindo que esteja **carregando uma configuração**, deveria usar `require_once`.

> Leitura recomendada: [SOpt - O que usar require/include/require_once/include_once?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15290/45810)

Continuando...

> o select+query+row esta apresentando erro

A função `mysqli_query()` espera que sejam passados 2 parâmetros: A conexão e a *query* em si.

Nos exemplos que você viu, a tal variável `$conn` é, **normalmente**, a conexão com o banco de dados. Por isso ela deve ser passada como **primeiro parâmetro** na função `mysqli_query()`.

Como você está *"trazendo a conexão em outro arquivo"*, você deve ter esse tal arquivo mais ou menos assim:

**config.php**:

```
<?php
$conexao = mysqli_connect(
    'localhost',
    'usuario_do_db',
    'senha_do_db',
    'nome_do_db'
);
```

Agora, para finalizar, corrija seu código:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');

$gasto = "select sum(buy) as buy from home;";  // Estava faltando delimitar (;)
$resultgasto = mysqli_query($conexao, $gasto);
$resultGasto_query = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultgasto);
?>
```

Lá em baixo no código você está buscando pela chave "buy":

```
<?php <td bgcolor="#FF6347">.$$resultGasto_query['buy'].</td>?>
```

Para entender melhor, veja as diferenças entre [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) e [mysqli_fetch_row()](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php).

Como está **tentando** retornar o valor pela chave *buy*, deve-se usar matriz associativa. Repare que na *query* solicitei que seja retornado como "buy": `sum(buy) as buy`.

Outra coisa! O *PHP* não vai renderizar a célula da tabela com essa sintaxe! Pode-se fazer isso de várias formas. Vou demonstrar algumas a fim de corrigir essa linha:

```
<td bgcolor="#FF6347"><?php echo $resultGasto_query['buy']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FF6347"><?= $resultGasto_query['buy']; ?></td>
<?php echo '<td bgcolor="#FF6347">'.$resultGasto_query['buy'].'</td>'; ?>
<?= '<td bgcolor="#FF6347">'.$resultGasto_query['buy'].'</td>'; ?>
<?php echo "<td bgcolor=\"#FF6347\">$resultGasto_query['buy']</td>"; ?>
```

Resumindo:
`<td bgcolor="#FF6347">...</td>` é *HTML*; `$resultGasto_query['buy']` é *PHP*, portanto deve ficar entre as *tags* do *PHP*: `<?php ?>` ou `<?= ?>` (*echo* abreviado).

Se seguiu as dicas corretamente, seu código deve funcionar. Caso não, lembre-se de editar a pergunta e postar "**exatamente a mensagem de erro retornada pelo *PHP***", ao invés de:

> esta apresentando erro.

Comment: Lipe, muito obrigado pela resposta, ainda sou novo na programação, mas suas respostas foram muito clara, e bastante acertivas. li sobre os topicos que me mandou e ja fiz os ajustes mudou o erro e agora pode ser pela forma que esta montado meu arquivo config. vou lhe mandar o erro e o arquivo config.

Comment: Que bom que gostou, @GabrielAlves! Edite a pergunta e poste o erro e a parte do código que gera o erro.

Comment: editei minha pergunta, ve se esta certo como fiz agora por favor.

Comment: @GabrielAlves, repare que vc está misturando `mysqli` com `PDO`. Tá errado mesmo, uai! Utilize a conexão como mencionei aqui na resposta, com `mysqli_connect()`.

Comment: Lipe, ja deu certo mudando a conexao para aquele formato, o problema agora e que eu ja estava chamando alguns select no restante do codigo com pdo, e agora gera erro la, vou postar no codigo o trecho.

Comment: Então, agora é só ir corrigindo seu código. Só precisa lembrar-se de não misturar o *PDO* com o *MySQLi*... Legal seria vc usar um ou outro, mas nada contra vc usar os dois tb... *MySQLi* é interessante por ter funções estruturadas e orientação a objetos. *PDO* é só orientado a objetos...